# Java - POJO Serialization Jackson 2.0

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I've been scanning stack overflow all day and have not come across a viable solution for my problem.

I have a pojo that has primitive types and nested objects. For example...

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"duration", "errorCode", "haveFieldsChanged", 
"serviceRequestToken", "storedProcDuration"}) // Abstract Base Class 
 properties
class Bus extends AbstractBaseClass implements Serializable{

    @JsonIgnore
    private static final long serialVersionId = 1;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    int id;

    @JsonProperty("students")
    List<Student> students; // Nested Objects

    @JsonProperty("employer")
    Employer employer; //Nested object

    // Getters and setters - none are annotated

@JsonRootName(value = "student")
class Student implements Serializable{
    // student fields
}

@JsonRootName(value = "statusType")
class Employer implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    int id;
}
```

When I serialize my Bus object, jackson has no problem creating the proper structure for name, id, and my list of students. However, it will skip over Employer entirely leaving it absent from the json. See below.

```
{
  "name":"Sean",
  "id": 1,
  "students":[student objects...]
}
```

I have tried @JsonProperty, @JsonSerialize(as = Employer.class), I tried building map for the employer object. I feel like I have exhausted most options. Is there something I am missing?

I ran into stack overflow exceptions trying some other annotations. I appreciate any help I can get.

The reason I added @JsonProperty to the fields is to help drive deserialization. I think this may be the root cause for serialization, but I am not certain.

Serialization Implementation

```
private String serializeBus(Bus bus) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(bus);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        logger.error("Error serializing bus");
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    return json;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have created similar structure with getters and setters and it prints for me `employer` as well. Do you use any annotation or other kind of configuration? Which version of library do you use?

Comment: All of the code in your question is perfectly fine and not the reason for the non-serialization of the employee. Can you show us a Github repo or something similar with the way how you serialize the bus object?

Comment: Could `employer` be null ?

Comment: I have getters and setters in all classes. I use a handful of annotations. Please refer to my example code above. @MichałZiober

Comment: Unfortunately the code is proprietary and therefore, can not push it to github. @mle

Comment: Employer is not null, that is one of the first things I check when debugging the issue. @KedarJoshi

Comment: I am using fasterxml.jackson.core v2.6.1 @MichałZiober

Comment: Doesn't `Employer` need to implement `Serializable`?  It doesn't appear from what you posted to be an inner class.

Comment: @sruffatti, this code is perfectly valid and should work. Version `2.6.1` should be also OK. What do you have on the list of ignored properties `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"..."})`? Maybe there is a problem? Could you create smallest valid example which does not work? It will be much easier to help if we could work on the same structure as you? Right now it is a guessing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I implemented Serializable into Employer and Students. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @MichałZiober I included the list of ignored properties. These are all properties of the Abstract Base Class. Ill see if I can throw together an example. I realize it is only guessing right now. Im not sure how comfortable I am with posting anything remotely close to the code I am working on. The structure i've posted above is identical in structure.

Comment: @MichałZiober Added serialization method

Answer (score 0):

So, if it is not feasible for you to share code, then I put your example above in a little sandbox project: https://github.com/mle-enso/stackoverflow
It currently runs with Spring Boot 2.1 but also downgrading the managed Jackson version(s) to 2.6.1 has no negative impact.

Maybe you could try this project with a simple `mvn clean verify` or a manual test run of `de.mle.stackoverflow.jackson.BusSerializerTest` to dig further into this issue here.